# Why the Flutter (Dart) code below doesn't display a scroll bar?

Tags: android, flutter, scrollbar, singlechildscrollview, flutter-alertdialog

We can scroll the text up and down but no scroll bar is shown.

My purpose in showing the scroll bar was to make the user aware that there is more text below.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Scrollable Alert Dialog'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Scrollbar(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // add your scrollable content here
              // for example:
              for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
                Text('Item $i'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Close'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

[Snapshot of the resulting AlertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULTYX.jpg)

Comment: What exactly you are trying to get?  can you include an image/gif will be better

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the 20 items isn't enough to make it scrollable based on your viewport. SingleChildScrollView will be scrollable only when its child size is greater than its view port. Also, you may wrap the scrollable widget with `Scrollbar`
.

```dart
content: Scrollbar( // preferable 
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // add your scrollable content here
        // for example:
        for (var i = 1; i <= 220; i++) Text('Item $i'), //here 
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: 20 is enough for most Android emulators. Text items are for example only. I am using long description text in my app and no scroll bar is visible.

Comment: what do you get having `Scrollbar` as top widget

Comment: My purpose is that a vertical scroll bar becomes visible so user can perceive there is more text to read.

Comment: The AlertDialog content is wrapped inside a SingleChildScrollView and a Scrollbar widget. The Column widget inside the Scrollbar widget contains the scrollable content.

Answer (score 0):

This version worked!
Thanks to Yeasin Sheikh.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
  title: Text('Scrollable Alert Dialog'),
  content: Scrollbar(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
        children: [
          // add your scrollable content here
          // for example:
          for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            Text('Item $i'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  actions: [
    TextButton(
      child: Text('Close'),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    ),
  ],
  );
}
```